# Binding to an array's element changing with combobox index

Tags: c#, wpf, indexing, data-binding, combobox

```
class DAC : INotifyPropertyChanged
{
    private uint _value;
    private bool _isCurrent;
    private string _name;
    private uint _address;
    private bool _powerDown;
    private bool _lowPower;
    private bool _enable;

    public bool Enable
    {
        get { return _enable; }
        set 
        {
            if (_enable == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            _enable = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Enable");
        }
    }

    //The rest of the property definitions looks like the first one

    public uint Value
    {
        get { return _value; }
        set 
        {
            if (_value == value)
            {
                return;
            }
            _value = value;
            OnPropertyChanged("Value");
        }
    }

    #region INotifyProperty Definitions
    public event PropertyChangedEventHandler PropertyChanged;

    protected void OnPropertyChanged(string propertyName)
    {
        if (PropertyChanged != null)
        {
            PropertyChanged(this, new PropertyChangedEventArgs(propertyName));
        }
    } 
    #endregion
}
```

So this is my basic class, which I aim to use for populating a list. I basically have an array of DACs (or some other derivative of DAC) that I list on a combobox. 
The combobox populates itself with

```
combobox1.SetBinding(ComboBox.ItemsSourceProperty, new Binding() { Source = cdacList });
combobox1.DisplayMemberPath = "Name";
```

When user chooses one of the items in there, it is supposed to update a textbox's and a slider's values according to the index selected from combobox and use that index to access data from an array.

I tried directly binding with

```
textbox1.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty, new Binding("Address") { Source = cdacList[combobox1.SelectedIndex] });
slider1.SetBinding(Slider.ValueProperty, new Binding("Value") { Source = cdacList[combobox1.SelectedIndex] });
```

But it doesn't update itself. I know I need to get some other aspect to do this with binding but I just cant figure it out myself.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You should be able to set the bindings once like shown below, without a need to change them later:

```
textbox1.SetBinding(TextBox.TextProperty,
    new Binding("SelectedItem.Address") { Source = combobox1 });
slider1.SetBinding(Slider.ValueProperty,
    new Binding("SelectedItem.Value") { Source = combobox1 });
```

That said, the bindings should be created in XAML:

```
<TextBox x:Name="textbox1"
    Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Address, ElementName=combobox1}" .../>
<Sliderx:Name="slider1"
    Text="{Binding SelectedItem.Value, ElementName=combobox1}" .../>
```

Comment: That works flawlessly. I wasn't expecting it to be this simple. I also know that I should bind using XAML, but I still can't figure out how to bind normal variables without declaring locals, etc.